# Migration of Permission Sets through Change set gives error

Tags: error, change-set, permission-sets

I got an error while Migrating Permission Set from one Sandbox to another.

> Permission Read All A depends on permission(s): Read All B.

I have checked Object Setting for both the object and the assignment for both is Read and View All, but still  it gives the error

Please Help

Thanks
Nirav

Comment: I think it's due to Master-Detail relationship.If you don't specify permissions for the master object B then you shouldn't specify "view all" or "modify all" on the detail object A as permissions on child is controlled by parent.